# escaping the double quotes in python string

Tags: python, escaping

I've a question about double quotes escaping in python string formatting. for example,

```
    print "How tall are you?",

    height = raw_input()

    print "So you are %r tall" % height
```

when I put 5" 6' , it returns ' 5\'6" ' and i don't get why there is a backslash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for the representation of the string. Since the string contains *both* types of quotes, one type *must* be escaped in order for it to be a proper representation. If you only want what was typed then use `%s` instead.