# How ' would " you ''' save """ this whole title as a string?

Tags: python, string

In Python, how would you save the above string to a variable, if you hypothetically had to?

Edit: The situation I am hypothetically thinking of is if you have a function which copies the contents of a website/PDF to a variable (ex. with Pyperclip) and then do something with that variable. Having a single quote, double quote, three single quotes and three double quotes would immediately cause an error in every solution proposed thus far.

Comment: pls clarify this question with more detail. and what is the need for saving an explicit string to a variable when you can you implement it?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. How would I assign to a variable "x" the following string:

How ' would “ you ''' save ”“” this string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [escaping the double quotes in python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276820/escaping-the-double-quotes-in-python-string)

Comment: There is a difference between the textual representation of a string literal in python source and the string itself in a variable. If you have a function that copies the contents of a web site, you don't need the escapes that the same string in a python source file would need. Nothing special needs to happen if this is what you mean by "save to a variable".

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to type this as a string, it will not work. However if you are pulling the line of data into a variable, Python will automatically backslash the `chars` it needs to.

This is evident if you attempt to pull this line from a file using `open()` and `readlines()`, and you will get the same result if you parse a `HTML` file using `BeautifulSoup`.

File contains:

```
How ' would " you ''' save """ this whole title as a string?
```

Open and `readlines()`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    test = list(file.readlines())

print(test)
```

Outputs:

```
['How \' would " you \'\'\' save """ this whole title as a string?']
```

`HTML` file:

```
<doctype='HTML'>
How ' would " you ''' save """ this whole title as a string?
</>
```

From `HTML`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('data.html'), "html.parser")

text = soup.get_text()

print(type(text), text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'str'> How ' would " you ''' save """ this whole title as a string?
```

And when you append it to a list, it returns the string including the char escapes.

```
test.append(text.strip())

print(test)
```

Outputs:

```
['How \' would " you \'\'\' save """ this whole title as a string?']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "How\' would \" you\"\' save\"\"\" this string?"
>>> print(a)
How' would " you"' save""" this string?
```

Use backslashes to escape the quotes.

Comment: This is not at all similar to my string

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, someone edited it so I'll edit my answer to fix that.

Comment: what is wrong with this answer? @SlayinAlive if you requested for quotes like in your question `"""`

Comment: The string is the whole title.

Comment: cool, this question needs to be re-worded, as it's not clear at all.

Comment: Edited my answer. Also, the title was different at first, I'm assuming the formatting went wrong but the title first requested to only save """ as string.

Comment: @SlayinAlive - (1) paste to a text editor and save as a text file and write your python program to read that file. Alternatively, write a quick python program that reads the file and prints the `repr` of the string. (2) write a python program that uses as module such as [clipboard](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/) to read the current contents of the clipboard and print the `repr`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
s = """How ' would “ you ''' save ”“” this string?"""
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because you already have 3 double quotes in between 'save' and 'this'

Comment: Have you actually tried it?
I did, by copypasting the title of your question, and it did work.

Comment: This only works because ```"``` and ```”``` are different characters, which I'm assuming is because of the title formatting them like that automatically. Making all of them normal ```"``` would cause this to fail.